# Why does this php string comparison work?

Tags: php, string-comparison, boolean-logic

The code:

```
  $fn0 ='Joe';
  $sn = 'Bloggs';
  $fn1 = 'Joseph';
  if (  (!strcasecmp($fn0, $first_name))
        ||(!strcasecmp($fn1, $first_name))
        &&(!strcasecmp($sn, $last_name))
      ){
        echo('<h3>Hello Joe Bloggs!</h3>');
        }
```

Works perfectly.

But why?

If NOT (fn0) OR NOT (fn1) AND ALSO NOT (sn) THEN PRINT "Hello Joe Bloggs"

Surely it should display "hello Joe Bloggs" for everything that is *not* Joe Bloggs, yet this is not the case: it will display the above message iff ($first_name == "joe" || "joseph") && $last_name == "bloggs".

Can anyone decipher this?

Comment: Because ["*`strcasecmp` returns ... 0 if the two strings are equal.*"](http://us.php.net/strcasecmp). `!0 == true`.

Comment: your code is `If  (NOT(fn0) OR NOT(fn1))==true AND NOT(sn)==true THEN PRINT ...`

Answer (score 1):

look at your parenthesis

```
if ( ( !strcasecmp($fn0, $first_name) || !strcasecmp($fn1, $first_name) )
    && ( !strcasecmp($sn, $last_name) ) ) {
...
}
```

the mistake is the logic with `||` and `&&`. If the first check is true, the rest will be ignored

Comment: @bukifixart You are right - but that's not the answer. I think that DCoder was right: it returns 0 which is interpreted as 'false'; so the negation of this value is required - quite confusing.

Comment: well, the negation of a "non-true-interpreted-value" should be true, where's the confusion?

Comment: Well it is confusing that the function be designed that way; I would have expected it to return true if equal; but although unintuitive, can be worked around easily enough.

Comment: m(  please look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php: "Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal."

This function is to compare strings, not only to check equality. It would be easier to do `if (in_array( $first_name, array( $fn0, $fn1 ) ) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

After the first comparison results in TRUE, the "or" condition is not needed.  Of course, we have to assume that there is some definition for $first_name somewhere...

Comment: Man Page References: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php  http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php